# Grails cache plugin: Why do we have targetObjectHashCode in CacheKey?

Tags: grails, caching, grails-plugin

Grails cache plugin's custom cache key has following four elements:

```
grails.plugin.cache.CustomCacheKeyGenerator$CacheKey {
    final String targetClassName;
    final String targetMethodName;
    final int targetObjectHashCode;
    final Object simpleKey;
}
```

Complete source is available [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/cache/CustomCacheKeyGenerator.java)

I need to understand why do we have **targetObjectHashCode** as part of the key?

The reason I am asking this is because it causes cache misses while using it with ehcache (which has **diskPersistent** enabled).

In most cases, target objects are DAOs; and they won't have **hashCode()** implemented. Now every time a JVM restarts, all elements loaded from disk will have a cache miss because the hashcode of the target object changes.

Comment: I don't know the answer offhand but I left a question on the commit at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache/commit/f2d263767d00a3102f3361a1d3875dea3c43ee14 where it appears that may have been introduced.

Comment: I could see that the documentation specifies that hashCode() should be overridden. But I am still curious to know the reason behind having these additional target fields, instead of spring's org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey. 

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache/blob/f2d263767d00a3102f3361a1d3875dea3c43ee14/src/docs/guide/usage.gdoc

Comment: I understood...this jira explains it. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11736

Comment: I am glad you got it worked out.